# caffe solver document. how to understand the momentum μ has an effect of factor $1/(1-μ)$?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

in http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/solver.html

it said

> Note that the momentum setting μ
> effectively multiplies the size of your updates by a factor of 1/(1-μ)
> after many iterations of training, so if you increase μ
> , it may be a good idea to decrease α accordingly (and vice versa).

My question is:

> 1. why 1/(1-μ) , how to prove that?
> 2. why it's a good idea to decrease α according to an increasing μ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, it's the sum of a Geometric Progression.

Update with momentum means that the "velocity" and "position" are updated as follows:

v = μ * v + α * gradient

θ = θ - v

Now, assuming that initially v = 0 and the gradient remains (nearly) constant (say 1 for convenience), the velocity evolves as:

- 0,
- α,
- (1 + μ) * α,
- (1 + μ(1 + μ)) * α = (1 + μ + μ^2) * α,
- (1 + μ + μ^2 + μ^3) * α,
- (1 + μ + μ^2 + μ^3 + μ^4) * α,
- (1 + μ + μ^2 + μ^3 + μ^4 + μ^5) * α,
- ...
- 1/(1 - μ) * α

(Using the formula for the sum of an infinite geometric progression)

**EDIT**: To answer the second part of your question, (adding to @Prune's answer below) the 1/(1 - μ) * α behaves more or less like an "effective learning rate".  So if some particular value of α was working well before you changed μ, you should compensate by decreasing α to keep the "effective learning rate" constant.  This is as important as selecting the correct learning rate in gradient descent without momentum.

Comment: In what kind of situation could my gradient remains nearly constant?

Comment: @Long, the 1/(1 - μ) is just an approximation. Usually, as you start converging towards the solution, your gradient will start decreasing. In this case the multiplicative factor you put in front of the current gradient will be even higher.

You acquire a high velocity because _previously_ the gradient was higher, but now the gradient value is low, and the relative contribution of the momentum term is more than before.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking to your second point, you generally want the velocity tuned to a value compatible with your problem.  The velocity describes the movement of your estimated solution point.  If the velocity is too small, you converge too slowly, and/or overfit; if it's too large, you can thrash around the solution point, and even fail to converge.

Most algorithms will have controls for this second problem, often simply reducing α by a small factor (such as .01) whenever we find a new best-ever loss.  The part you need to control is your initial setting.  If you increase μ such that 1/(1-μ) goes up by a factor of 1.25, try reducing α by 20% to compensate.

Comment: Thank you Prune, I understand now!